issues run android in react native
Running Android in React Native has issues with the Android display:
The development server returned response error code: 500
URL: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle ?platform=android&dev=true&lazy=true&minify =false&app=com.yuda&modulesOnly=false& runModule=true

Body:
{"originModulePath":"C: \MobileApp\Yuda\Navigation.tsx" ,"targetModuleName":"@react-navigation /stack", "message":"Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/stack from C:\MobileApp\ \Yuda\Navigation.tsx: @react-navigation/stack could not be found within the project or in these directories:\n node_modules\n ..\ \node_modules\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m 1| \u001b[39m \u001b[36mimport\u001b[39m \u001b[33mReact\u001b[39m \u001b[36mfrom\u001b[39m \u001b[32m'react'\u001b[39m\u001b[33m; \u001b[39m\n \u001b[90m 2 |\u001b[39m \u001b[36mimport\u001b[39m {\u001b[33mNavigationContainer\u001b[39m} \u001b[36mfrom\u001b[39m \u001b[32m'@react-navigation/native'\u001b[ 39m\u001b[33m;\u001b[39m\n\u001b[31m\u 001b[1m>\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[90m 3 |\u001b[39m \u001b[36mimport\u001b[39m {createStackNavigator}

I hope someone can help with the error in my Android display

can you provide package.json file ?

install @react-navigation/stack

You should see in your package.json that @react-navigation/stack is defined like this;
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29"

If you have this and still see this error, try running this on your terminal on the project directory;
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081


It seems like you haven't installed @react-navigation/stack. Please verify it.
